# How to draw a polygon that reflects data changes using binding in wpf xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I need to draw a coordinate system, and inside this coordinate system, I want to draw a polygon based on points from measured data.
When the data changes, the polygon points should change accordingly.

Everything should scale to the size of the "container", although perspective should be kept consistent.

I am new to wpf and binding, so I do not know which part to bind, or to what kind of collection, to be able to reflect changes.

BTW, is there a way to do a general conversion of all coordinate references, so 0,0 will be in the lower left corner, or must everything be calculated seperately?

Comment: Do you know anything about the range of input data? Here you can find few information about how to draw on canvas: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

"is there a way to do a general conversion of all coordinate references, so 0,0 will be in the lower left corner, or must everything be calculated seperately?"

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by this, but because you can bind to the points to a point collection in code behind you can do whatever you like to the points programmatically.

Here is an answer with a good simple example of binding polygon points:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13571386/1624581

Comment: Thanks for the help, but there is a problem with the shown code - the PropertyChanged event handler remains null. Where should this be assigned?

Comment: @TheRoadrunner Try assigning the event handler in the window's constructor, I believe that this can be done either before or after InitializeComponent().

Comment: Of course the (y-)coordinates can easily be calculated in the classes behind the points collection. Thank you for your answer, but I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263936/changing-a-polygons-points to be a better working sample.